# How to configure MySQL Connection String 'useAffectedRows' in a specific session/connection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

The Connection String way:

> jdbc:mysql://ip:port/db?useAffectedRows=true&…

How to set up 'useAffectedRows'in a specific session/connection, not as global settings?

Comment: Create a new connection for the session that does use the 'useAffectedRows' when you need it. The code structure determines global settings so without code or a session criteria this is a bit ambigious. Alternately `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` when you specifically need it (ref: [ROW_COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count))

Comment: nice, but how to ensure that `SELECT ROW_COUNT()` statement is executed right after the update statement? open a transaction can help? @danblack

Comment: As long as its executed in the same connection after the update, before other statements that change its results, it will have the right results.